# What can cause programatically created pages to occasionally disappear, but always come back when update.php is run

Tags: nodes

I have a page, very basic it's just some HTML and some Anchor tags, it works fine except occasionally and without consistency it just disappears and I instead get a 404, nothing fixes this no matter how many refreshes, flushing caches etc, but as soon as I run update.php the page returns again until it next decides to go on a journey.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? What are the likely culprits? I've read about empty module files causing similar inconsistencies and odd EOF elements but I've checked and double checked all my custom modules for these issues and nothings come up.

```
$items['management'] = array(
'title'            => '',
'page callback'    => '_xxx_management',
'type'             => MENU_CALLBACK,
'access arguments' => array('fusi booking manager'),
);
```

This $items array is in a seperate menu.inc that's included in my main module as its rather large. Within the hook_menu function. It ends with return $items; as you'd expect

```
function _xxx_management()
{
        $html = '<div id="dashboard">
        <a href="/management/content">Content</a>
        <a href="/management/properties/units">Properties</a>
        <a href="/management/bulk_room_management">Availability</a>
        <a href="/management/bookings">Bookings</a>
        <a href="/management/email">Email</a>

        <a href="/management/reports/occupancy/current">Current Occupants</a>
        <a href="/management/pricing">Pricing</a>
        <a href="/management/reports">Reports</a>
        <a href="/management/settings">Settings</a>
        </div>';

       return $html;
}
```

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: "...programmatically created pages..." can be the hint to track down the problem. You need to provide a bit detailed information, for instance paste the code you wrote to create the pages..

Comment: Hi I've added the relevant code to my original post

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you used `MENU_CALLBACK` instead of `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` as type?

Comment: I don't want this to appear in menu's anywhere, instead I manually link to it, beyond that reasoning no

Comment: does everything else work in this module?  sounds like it is being disabled somehow and thus the menu isn't being included.

Comment: Yep everything works, just this one page that doesn't there's around 50 other pages that the module creates that all work even when this page has disappeared, adding to the oddity!